# Rx - Reducing a list of numbers to a series of (number,count)

Tags: rx-java

Let's say we have a sequence of numbers:

`0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,1`

I'm looking for Rx observable that would reduce this sequence to pairs containing (element, group_count_of_this_element). So the above would become:

  `(0,4) // first 4 "0" occurred
  (1,2) // then there were two "1"s
  (2,3) // then came three "2"s, one after another
  (3,1) // and one occurrence of "3"
  (4,3) // three "4"
  (0,4) // four zeros
  (2,1) // and two "1"s`

I'm still learning, and can't really grasp this. I'm suspecting collect might be of help, but couldn't even find a good example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the effect via `publish` and `buffer` with an Observable boundary but I find it too convoluted. I find it much simpler to write an operator where the data and the buffer-changing decision is in a single place:

```
public final class BufferUntilChanged<T, U> 
implements Operator<List<T>, T> {
    final Func1<? super T, U> keySelector;

    public BufferUntilChanged(Func1<? super T, U> keySelector) {
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super List<T>> t) {
        BufferUntilChangedSubscriber<T, U> parent = 
                new BufferUntilChangedSubscriber<>(t, keySelector);
        t.add(parent);
        return parent;
    }

    static final class BufferUntilChangedSubscriber<T, U> 
    extends Subscriber<T> {
        final Func1<? super T, U> keySelector;
        final Subscriber<? super List<T>> actual;

        List<T> list;
        U lastKey;

        public BufferUntilChangedSubscriber(
                Subscriber<? super List<T>> actual,
                Func1<? super T, U> keySelector) {
            this.keySelector = keySelector;
            this.actual = actual;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            U u;

            try {
                u = keySelector.call(t);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                unsubscribe();
                actual.onError(e);
                return;
            }

            boolean doRequest;
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                lastKey = u;
                doRequest = true;
            } else
            if (!Objects.equals(lastKey, u)) {
                actual.onNext(list);
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                doRequest = false;
            } else {
                doRequest = true;
            }
            list.add(t);

            lastKey = u;

            if (doRequest) {
                request(1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            actual.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            if (list != null) {
                actual.onNext(list);
            }
            actual.onCompleted();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is an example use:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<Integer> source = Observable.from(
                new Integer[] { 
                        0,0,0,0,
                        1,1,
                        2,2,2,
                        3,
                        4,4,4,
                        0,0,0,0,
                        1,1 });

        source.lift(new BufferUntilChanged<>(v -> v))
        .map(list -> new Integer[] { 
                list.get(0), list.size() 
        })
        .subscribe(v -> 
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v)));
    }
```

Comment: Ah, you again. Then the answer must be good. But let me check it first. And before I can check it I have to convert your code to Kotlin.

Comment: Hmmm... it must be something trivial, but how do i fix "source.lift(new BufferUntilChanged<>(v -> v))"? v -> v doesn't seem right (and won't compile, anyway)

Comment: I copied it from Eclipse which compiled it fine. Maybe this is one of the type inference bugs in javac. Try `(Integer v) -> v` or factor it out `Func1<Integer, Integer> f = v -> v;`

Comment: You must be some kind of genius. This is a wonderful piece of code, wish I could understand it. Anyway, as a bonus, here's example code in Kotlin: source.lift(BufferUntilChanged<Int,Int>({ v -> v }))
        .map{ list -> arrayOf(list[0], list.size) }
        .subscribe{ v -> println(Arrays.toString(v))}